# Icinga2 check_file_age always returns File not found

Tags: nagios, icinga2

I'm using `check_file_age` command with service created in icinga2 director. It always returns file not found.

```
FILE_AGE CRITICAL: File not found - /root/last-backup
```

The file exists on the server and returns OK if ran in terminal.

```
~ '/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_file_age' '-c' '95000' '-f' '/root/last-backup' '-w' '90000'
FILE_AGE OK: /root/last-backup is 70052 seconds old and 11 bytes | age=70052s;90000;95000 size=11B;0;0;0
```

If I check the debug.log, the command returns exit code 2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in permission, the agent is not able to access the file.

Move your file to different folder. Like `/var/backups/last-backup`.